# How can I store values in an array of structs? - Arduino Uno

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to make a struct of array where each index has its own set of properties. For example, I want channels[0].name to have its own name and channels[1].name to be different too.

Each time I have a new input, the old one is forgotten and shows the new one repeatedly. I would really appreciate some tips.

Part of the code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
#include <utility/Adafruit_MCP23017.h>

Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();
 #define LIMIT 26
 
 struct protocol {
  String name;
  char character;
  int values;
  int minimum;
  int maximum;
};

void create_channels() {
String details;
struct protocol channels[LIMIT];

int i = 0;

do {
       byte b = Serial.available();
        if (b != 0)
        {
          details = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
          details.trim();
          if (details.startsWith("C")) {
            Serial.print("Channel description: ");
            Serial.println(details);
            channels[i].name = details;
           for (i=0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
            channels[i].name = details;
            Serial.println(channels[i].name);
            }

          } else if (details.startsWith("V")) {
            
          } else if (details.startsWith("X")) {
            
          } else if (details.startsWith("N")) {
            
          }
           else {
            Serial.println("Invalid character");
          }
        }
      } while (1);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  lcd.setBacklight(7);

create_channels();


}

void loop() {
 
}
```

This is the result:

```
Channel description: CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
CAMain
Channel description: CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
CBSecondary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each string you read from the the serial input you're populating the whole `channels` array with that string and printing it out 'LIMIT' times.

Try taking out the for loop - and replacing it with:

```
channels[i++].name = details
```

Then change the `while(1);` condition to `while(i < LIMIT);` so the loop exits when the `channels` array is full.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with that bit. It's working now. I have a question from that though:  What does channels[i++] do in the end?

Comment: It shouldn't do because you're checking the start character and only add to the array if you get a match.

Comment: Ahhh OK that makes sense. Could you tell me what channels[i++] does as well? Just want to make sure I can remember this in the future

Comment: channels[i++] uses the post increment operator so will reference channels[i] for the assignment and then increment i once completed.